# NextJS useEffect doesn't wait for API response

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm struggling to get "lovedList" values as the page loads for the first time. When re-rendering, the list is correctly updated. How can I make it so it waits for the list values to render the first objects from useEffect?

```js
import { Post, PostProps } from "./Post";
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { api } from "../services/api";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/client";

export function PostList() {
  const [session, status] = useSession();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState<PostProps[]>([])
  const [skip, setSkip] = useState(0)
  const take = 3

  let list = []

  async function getUserPurchases() {
    if (session) {
      const response = await api.get(`/purchases/${session?.id}`)

      response.data.map(purchase => {
        list.push(purchase.postId)
      })
    }

    return list
  }

  async function handleLoadMore() {
    setLoading(true)
    const lovedList = await getUserPurchases();
    setSkip(skip + take)
    const newPosts = await api.get(`/post?take=${take}&skip=${skip}`)

    const formattedData = newPosts.data.map(post => {
      console.log(lovedList)
      return {
        id: post.id,
        image: post.image,
        institution: post.institution,
        title: post.title,
        description: post.description,
        createdAt: new Date(post.createdAt).toLocaleDateString('pt-BR', {
          day: '2-digit',
          month: 'long',
          year: 'numeric'
        }),
        loved: lovedList.includes(post.id),
        author: {
          image: post.author.image,
          name: post.author.name,
          id: post.author.id
        }
      }
    })

    setData([...data, ...formattedData])
    setLoading(false)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleLoadMore()
  }, [])

  if (loading) {
    return <h1>Carregando</h1>
  }
  return (
    <main className="flex flex-col md:max-w-3xl xl:max-w-6xl mx-auto text-gray-200 text-6xl ">
      {data && data.map(post => (
        <Post
          key={post.id}
          image={post.image}
          institution={post.institution}
          title={post.title}
          description={post.description}
          createdAt={post.createdAt}
          loved={post.loved}
          author={post.author}
          id={post.id}
        />
      ))}

      <button
        type="button"
        className="px-4 py-3 bg-blue-400 rounded-full outline-none flex items-center 
        justify-center text-sm my-16 mx-auto w-4/12 hover:bg-blue-500
        transition-colors duration-200 ease-out"
        onClick={handleLoadMore}
      >
        Carregar Mais
      </button>
    </main>
  );
}
```

When I load the page, the console.log returns empty arrays. If the next few items load, they console.log the propper list. How can I make it so it load properly when accessing the page for the first time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huge thanks to Joseph from Rockeseat for the solution!

Basically, If I want to have the list ready when the page is loaded, I need to use server-side rendering. Meaning I had to use the ServerSideProps from Next in the page that is using this component.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use either one of these:-

###### A. use your `loading` `state`

- only display `data` if `loading=false`

```
  return (
    <main className="flex flex-col md:max-w-3xl xl:max-w-6xl mx-auto text-gray-200 text-6xl ">
      {!loading 
        ? data.map(post => (
          <Post
            key={post.id}
            image={post.image}
            institution={post.institution}
            title={post.title}
            description={post.description}
            createdAt={post.createdAt}
            loved={post.loved}
            author={post.author}
            id={post.id}
          />
        ))
        : 'Loading...'
      }

      <button
        type="button"
        className="px-4 py-3 bg-blue-400 rounded-full outline-none flex items-center 
        justify-center text-sm my-16 mx-auto w-4/12 hover:bg-blue-500
        transition-colors duration-200 ease-out"
        onClick={handleLoadMore}
      >
        Carregar Mais
      </button>
    </main>
  );
```

###### B. set your `data` `state` **initially** to `undefined`

- currently you set them as `const [data, setData] = useState<PostProps[]>([])`
- change it to `undefined`, `const [data, setData] = useState<PostProps[]>()`. *I'm not sure whether you can do it like this or not. I've never use this `useState<Props>([])` `syntax` before*
- then your current **condition** `data && data.map(post => (...` will work as intended.
- It didn't work before cause `data` was set to be `[]`/**empty array** initially.

Comment: Both solutions don't make sense at all.

A for example, and again, the loading state does not affect the data retrieving, so the first ones that load with the page won't be available. Hence, the component will not reload.

As for B, that syntax means Typescript, it is just the types. I can't set to undefined otherwise there will be no way to iterate trough the list, as undefined is non-iterable.

Answer (score 0):

To validate the data array you should validate the lenght, because "data" constant already exist:

```
data.lenght > 0
```

additional to this you can add a prevent to the objects "?":

```
post?.id
```

Final code:

```js
import { Post, PostProps } from "./Post";
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { api } from "../services/api";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/client";

export function PostList() {
  const [session, status] = useSession();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState<PostProps[]>([])
  const [skip, setSkip] = useState(0)
  const take = 3

  let list = []

  async function getUserPurchases() {
    if (session) {
      const response = await api.get(`/purchases/${session?.id}`)

      response.data.map(purchase => {
        list.push(purchase.postId)
      })
    }

    return list
  }

  async function handleLoadMore() {
    setLoading(true)
    const lovedList = await getUserPurchases();
    setSkip(skip + take)
    const newPosts = await api.get(`/post?take=${take}&skip=${skip}`)

    const formattedData = newPosts.data.map(post => {
      console.log(lovedList)
      return {
        id: post.id,
        image: post.image,
        institution: post.institution,
        title: post.title,
        description: post.description,
        createdAt: new Date(post.createdAt).toLocaleDateString('pt-BR', {
          day: '2-digit',
          month: 'long',
          year: 'numeric'
        }),
        loved: lovedList.includes(post.id),
        author: {
          image: post.author.image,
          name: post.author.name,
          id: post.author.id
        }
      }
    })

    setData([...data, ...formattedData])
    setLoading(false)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleLoadMore()
  }, [])

  if (loading || data?.lenght === 0) {
    return <h1>Carregando</h1>
  }
  return (
    <main className="flex flex-col md:max-w-3xl xl:max-w-6xl mx-auto text-gray-200 text-6xl ">
      {data?.length > 0 && data?.map(post => (
        <Post
          key={post?.id}
          image={post?.image}
          institution={post?.institution}
          title={post?.title}
          description={post?.description}
          createdAt={post?.createdAt}
          loved={post?.loved}
          author={post?.author}
          id={post?.id}
        />
      ))}

      <button
        type="button"
        className="px-4 py-3 bg-blue-400 rounded-full outline-none flex items-center 
        justify-center text-sm my-16 mx-auto w-4/12 hover:bg-blue-500
        transition-colors duration-200 ease-out"
        onClick={handleLoadMore}
      >
        Carregar Mais
      </button>
    </main>
  );
}
```